# Extract text data from PCL using DELPHI code

Tags: excel, delphi, text, printer-control-language

I am looking for two things here...

1. Is there a way that i can read PCL file instructions to read the formats applied to the text, like BOLD, italics, and font size etc.
2. And I would like to know the way to extract text data without PCL instruction from PCL file, is there any option to Hack pcl file and remove PCL instructions from it.

   The background is, i am trying to convert existing Rave reports which creats PCL file into Excel based report using Flexcel3 component, i am finding it hard to read and extract data from PCL file. if i could get the text based output i would parse the data based on the field length and will create Excel report using Flexcel, if i could get the Format information from the PCL file i would apply those formats to the Excel. Need your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Either write, or use, a PCL parser.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response.... Its not a single report that i have to convert there are bunch of reports that i have to convert, i am trying to make it generic, writing would be lot of effort. and Regarding PCL parser is there any API or code that is available? any suggestion on that, because i am new to PCL stuffs.

Comment: I'm sure there are. Use websearch.